# Why does github this type of problem occur?

Tags: html, css, github, frontend, web-deployment

I have tried several time to open a Github account but it didn't accept me & continously showen me this type of something. (Unable to verify your captcha response. Please visit https://docs.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-connectivity-problems/#troubleshooting-the-captcha for troubleshooting information.)

someone can help me please to solve this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about a programming problem. Contact Github customer support instead.

Answer (score -2):

Since Bangladesh is listed in the countries where SMS authentication is supported, I don't suppose your issues are linked to [sanctioned countries](https://docs.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-and-trade-controls#githubcom) GitHub would refuse to deal with.

Try first from another computer and network, to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem yesterday, you must use vpn or proxy connection first (in some countries like Iran and Middle East countries) and then you can create a Github account, connect to a vpn - proxy like " hoxx vpn proxy Extension in your browser" or use psiphon before creating an account.